# Django pagination is not working properly with very large dataset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-pagination

When I use pagination with a very large dataset, it works too slow. Maybe I am not implementing it properly. Please help. How to make it fast? Is there anything that I can change or implement so that it works fine?

> view.py

```
def display(request):
    user_list = Final.objects.all()
    searchlen= user_list.count()
    paginator = Paginator(user_list, 100)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    users = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request,'displayLogs.html',{'users': users,'searchlen':searchlen})
```

> model.py

```
class Final(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(db_column='Date',primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
    corr = models.TextField(db_column='CorrelationId', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

```html
      <tbody>
 <tr class="gradeX">
 {% for item in users %}
 <td>{{item.dat}}</td>
 <td>{{item.act}}</td>
 <td>{{item.actor}}</td>
 <td class="center">{{item.tar}}</td>
 </tr>
       
 {% endfor %}
</tbody>


<div class="pagination" style="border-style:inset;border-width:5px;padding-bottom: 5px">
 {% if users.has_previous %}

 <a class="pagination-action" href="?page=1"> <i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></a>

 <a class="pagination-action" href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number}}"> <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></a>

 {% endif %}

 {% for num in users.paginator.page_range %}
  {% if users.number == num %}

   <span class="pagination-number pagination-current"><strong>{{ num }}</strong></span>

  {% elif num > users.number|add:'-3' and num < users.number|add:'3' %}

  <a class="pagination-number" href="?page={{ num }}">{{num}}</a>

  {% endif %}

 {% endfor %}

 {% if users.has_next %}

 <a class="pagination-action" href="?page={{ users.next_page_number }}"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
 <a class="pagination-action" href="?page={{ users.paginator.num_pages }}"> <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"> </i></a>

 {% endif %}
    
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging which parts are slow? Have you checked for database issues, like missing indices?

Comment: there is no error in database

Comment: And what about missing indices? Does the slow query log contain something relevant?

Comment: i am working with more then 50 lakh rows in my database

Comment: So, you are sure that database performance is not an issue?

Comment: yes please help

Comment: Sorry, then I'm out of ideas. You should share more details, like the underlying database structure including the configured indices, and sample data and queries

Comment: You could be having N+1 problems. Look into the Django Debug Toolbar and the database performance. You can also share the entire template that is being rendered. The part that loops over `users` will be especially insightful.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing something like this for large dataset. I attach my design as given below. Here click `<<` to go first page , `>>` to go last page , `<` to go previous page and `>` to go next page.

```
<tbody>
    {% for item in users %}
      <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>{{item.dat}}</td>
        <td>{{item.act}}</td>
        <td>{{item.actor}}</td>
        <td class="center">{{item.tar}}</td>
      </tr>                 
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
<nav aria-label="pagination" class="pagination_area">
<div class="row">
  {% if users.end_index > 0 %}
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 d-none d-md-block">
    <p>Showing {{ users.start_index }} to {{ users.end_index }} of {{ users.paginator.count}}.</p>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if users.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 dataTables_pager">
    <ul class="pagination">
      {% if users.has_previous %}

        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" data-page="1" href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number }}">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        {% if users.previous_page_number > 1 %}
          <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link " data-page="{{users.previous_page_number}}"  href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number }}">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}

      {% endif %}

      {% if users.previous_page_number > 2 %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link " data-page="{{users.number|add:'-2'}}" href="?{{users.number|add:'-2'}}"> {{ users.number|add:"-2" }} </a>
         </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link " data-page="{{users.number|add:'-1'}}" href="?page={{users.number|add:'-1'}}"> {{ users.number|add:"-1" }} </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}

      <li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link ">{{ users.number }}</span></li>

      {% if users.paginator.num_pages > users.number|add:"2" %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link " data-page="{{users.number|add:'1'}}" href="?page={{users.number|add:'1'}}"> {{ users.number|add:"1" }} </a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link " data-page="{{users.number|add:'2'}}" href="?page={{users.number|add:'2'}}"> {{ users.number|add:"2" }} </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}

      {% if users.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link " data-page="{{users.next_page_number}}" href="?page={{ users.next_page_number }}">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link " data-page="{{users.paginator.num_pages}}" href="?page={{users.paginator.num_pages}}">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
</nav>
```

[image]

This is my design. You can change design for your requirement.